# Using NameOf with a variable

Tags: .net, vb.net, nameof

Why doesn't any of the following compile:

```
NameOf(value.GetType())
NameOf(GetType(value))
```

> > This expression doesn't have a name.

How can I get the string name of the *type* of the value that was passed? `ToString()` might be overloaded, so can't use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `NameOf` in that case because this new operator gets the name of a member from the member itself.

`GetType` doesn't return *the member* but the type metadata of a class, structure, interface or enumeration.

Thus, you'll be able to get the whole type name getting the `Type.Name` property value: `value.GetType().Name`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `value.GetType().Name` to get the name of type as a string

Your code doesn't compile because `GetType()` returns an object of type `System.Type`, as opposed to an expression, which is required, per [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Any clue on why `NameOf` doesn't work here even though its argument is explicitly named `typeOrMember`?

Comment: Per [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx), the argument needs to be an expression, not an object. Recommended solution per MSDN is to use [TypeOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx) in conjunction with NameOf.

Comment: Fast and accurate. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: I just went through the entire thing again and think you're right.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I updated my answer to address both questions in the original post (which I thought I did earlier via a comment response...)

Comment: @CoolBots Now it answers the question!

Answer (score 1):

VB .Net has a built-in function named [TypeName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5422sfdf(v=vs.90).aspx).  Instead of getting the object type prior to getting that type name, you can pass an object directly to the `TypeName` function:

Comment: Great piece of info. No one else suggested this.

Comment: I affraid `TypeName` not usefull in some cases. For example for variable of type Array of Integer returned name will be `"Integer()"` or if variable is `null` then `"Nothing"` will be returned.